# Assignment associativity

Tags: javascript

The assignment operator has **right-to-left** associativity. So

```
var x,y;
x=y=1;
```

works as expected and x equals 1. Consider now the code:

```
var foo={};
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

I would expect the above to work like the following:

```
var foo = {n: 2}; 
foo.x=foo;
```

However, in the first case foo.x is `undefined` while in the second case `foo.x points to foo` (circular reference). Any explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript evaluates expressions from left to right. We can show what's going on by using an additional variable:

```
var foo = {};
var bar = foo;  // keep a reference to the object originally stored in foo
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

Because of associativity, the last statement is parsed as:

```
foo.x = (foo = {n: 2});
```

But because of evaluation order, `foo.x` runs first (determining where to store the value), then `foo`, then `{n: 2}`. So we store `{n: 2}` in the variable `foo`, then assign the same value to the property `x` of the old contents of `foo` ... which we can see by looking at `bar`:

```
foo = {"n" : 2}
bar = {"x" : {"n" : 2 }}
```

Comment: Any reference to back the claim that assignment expressions are evaluated from left to right?

Comment: @haim770 I found "*ECMAScript specifies left to right evaluation of expressions*" in http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/.

Comment: If interpreter store `{n: 2}` in variable `foo`, and *then* assign the same value to the property `x`, why variable `foo` contains the old content? I don't understand.

Comment: @YuriBeliakov What do you mean by "old content"?