# Double-assignment of an object property results in undefined property

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator

Can anyone tell how the output became `undefined`?

```
var foo = {n: 2};
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
console.log(foo.x); // undefined
```

Comment: Whats interesting is test.x is not undefined,

Comment: do you want something like this foo.x = foo, {n:2}; no?

Comment: @le_m Wondering... How did you get hold of that question?? :~)

Comment: @Shubh I upvoted it not too long ago :)

Comment: @le_m Great!! I got a good question to bookmark eventually :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```js
> foo.x = foo = { n: 2 };
> ```

The `foo.x` refers to the property `x` of the object referred to by `foo`. However, `foo = { n: 2 }` assigns a completely new object to `foo`. `x` is indeed assigned to an object, but that object is immediately replaced by another object. The object with the `x` property isn’t referenced by anything anymore.

You can read that line as

```js
foo.x = (foo = { n: 2 });
```

---

### Graphical explanation

```js
var foo = { n: 2 };
```

[image: First object is assigned to foo]

```js
foo.x = foo = { n: 2 };
```

[image: foo is reassigned to a second object, but foo.x still points to the first object.]

```js
console.log(foo.x);
```

[image: Trying to access foo.x actually accesses the x property of the second object.]

Comment: As far as I know, assignment expressions are evaluated from right to left...

Comment: They are, but the `foo.x` _still_ refers to the previous object.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/37763275/1625737, the reason is that they're actually evaluated from left to right...

Answer (score 2):

I'll break down the assignment and output of each variable as it plays out.

```
var foo = {n:2}
// foo: Object {n: 2}
// foo.x: undefined

foo.x = 3
// foo: Object {n: 2, x: 3 }
// foo.x: 3

foo.x = foo
// foo: Object {n: 2, x: Object {n:2, x: Object (recursive) } }
// foo.x: Object {n: 2, x: Object {n:2, x: Object (recursive) } }

foo.x = foo = {n: 2}
// foo: Object {n: 2}
// foo.x: undefined
```

The last line, as you can see, resets `foo` to equal `{n: 2}` which makes `foo.x` non-existent (because you have overwritten the `foo` object)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is exactly the same as this one,

```
var foo = {n:2}; // foo ==> {n:2}
foo.x = {n:2}; // foo ==> {n:2,x:{n:2}}
foo = {n:2}; // foo ==> {n:2}
console.log(foo.x); // undefined
```

because there's no "x" key in your object

Comment: is it though? Arent assignment expressions evaluated from right to left?

Comment: What ?

Assignment are sequential !

you should interpret  each line sequentially