# javascript object reference assignment results in undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a problem understanding reference assignments in JS.

```js
var foo = { n: 1 };
var bar = foo;

bar.n = 3;

console.log(foo.n);
console.log(bar.n);

foo.x = foo = { n: 2 };

console.log(foo.n);
console.log(foo.x);
console.log(foo.x.n);
```

I expected the last 2 console logs to be:

```
console.log(foo.x); // Javascript object {n: 2}
console.log(foo.x.n); // 2
```

but the actual output is undefined and execution error respectively.

Comment: Tell us what you think `foo.x = foo = {n: 2};` does and why you are writing it that way

Comment: Right. this will just assign that object to both foo.x and foo.

Comment: So the '=' operator is right-sided. Therefore first foo = {n: 2} is executed, so foo.n property becomes 2? Then foo.x should be assigned the result of the (foo = {n: 2}) expression, which I thought would be foo's Javascript object reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript code trick :What's the value of foo.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342809/javascript-code-trick-whats-the-value-of-foo-x) and [Why is the value of foo.x undefined in foo.x = foo = {n: 2}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933210) and [Multiple left-hand assignment with JavaScript, really right associative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371980) and [Assignment associativity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763113)

Comment: @adiga—yes, lot of dupes. :-)

Comment: It might help if you do `console.log(bar)` to find the missing *x* property. ;-) i.e. the object initially referenced by *foo* (and also referenced by *bar*) gets the *x* property, but now *foo* references a different object.

Answer (score 1):

your one-line assignment like this

> foo.x = foo = { n: 2 };

caused that foo got reference to `{ n: 2 }` erasing the previous definition with `x` property, so when you try to print `console.log(foo.x);` it prints `undefined`